# How can I add click event and go to other view?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am learning about WFM MVVM pattern.But I can't understand how can I add the click event to go to different view.

**View**

```
<UserControl x:Class="Paywall.Presentation.Views.Custom"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
             xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
             xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Paywall.Presentation.Views"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="dgData" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding GetCustomInvoicesVms}" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <materialDesign:DataGridTextColumn Header="OrderDescription" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Description}"/>
                <materialDesign:DataGridTextColumn Header="CustomerName" Width="*" Binding="{Binding CustomerName}"/>
                <materialDesign:DataGridTextColumn Header="Amount" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Amount}"/>
                <materialDesign:DataGridTextColumn Header="PhoneNumber" Width="*" Binding="{Binding PhoneNumber}"/>
                <materialDesign:DataGridTextColumn Header="PartNumber" Width="*" Binding="{Binding PartNumber}"/>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="#">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFlatDarkBgButton}" ToolTip="MaterialDesignFlatDarkButton">Pay</Button>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**ViewModel**

```
using Paywall.Application.Invoice.Queries;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Paywall.Presentation.ViewModels
{
    class CustomViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private ObservableCollection<GetCustomInvoicesVm> _GetCustomInvoicesVms;

        public CustomViewModel()
        {
            var query = new GetCustomInvoicesQuery(_url, _accessKey);

            _GetCustomInvoicesVms = new ObservableCollection<GetCustomInvoicesVm>(query.GetData());
        }

        public ObservableCollection<GetCustomInvoicesVm> GetCustomInvoicesVms
        {
            get { return _GetCustomInvoicesVms; }
        }
    }
}
```

Please, help me out. Thanks :)

Comment: `I can't understand how can I add the click event` what have you tried that you can't understand? Please update post to include what' you've tried and what isn't working so we can further help you out.

Comment: This page illustrates one way of doing viewmodel first https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/52485.wpf-tips-and-tricks-using-contentcontrol-instead-of-frame-and-page-for-navigation.aspx